# Finding all instances of a certain string

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if there was a way to filter a range full of "random text".

Columns B (cell B4) holds all of this random text. This looks something like this:

```
ColumnB
------
Apple2
Apple45
Apple62
Strawberry23
Orange
Apple312
Apple978
Apple725
Apple6
Peanut32
Orange23
Pear32
```

I was wondering if I could filtered all the text that has apple in it to a separate column and have it look like something like this in cell C4:

```
ColumnC
-------
Apple2
Apple45
Apple62
Apple312
Apple978
Apple725
Apple6
```

Please note that all of this text is all in one cell and not broken up in different rows.

EDIT:
This is what I have so far:

```
Sub WildcardSearch()

For Each Rname In Range("B4")
    If Rname.Value Like "*Apple*" Then
        Split("B4", vbLf)
    End If
    
Next Rname

End Sub
```

I was wondering if there was a way to build an array with new strings added to the array after it finds another "apple"? Not sure if im thinking along the right direction though.

Comment: Use `Split(B4Value, vbLf)` to get an array of values, then loop over that looking for "Apple' - add any matching value to C4

Comment: No need for VBA.  Just use the Advanced Filter and select to show the results in another location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```vb
Sub test1()
    Range("C4").Value = Join(Filter(Split(Range("B4"), vbLf), "apple", True, vbTextCompare), vbLf)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Function of this .... `Function FilterInCellString(SelectCell As Range, FltCriteria As String) As String
    FilterInCellString = Join(Filter(Split(SelectCell, vbLf), FltCriteria, True, vbTextCompare), vbLf)
End Function` ... In cell C4 enter function like `=FilterInCellString(B4,"Apple")`

Comment: @Naresh `SelectCell(1)` is more correct - if `SelectCell` consists of several cells, an error will occur in `Split(SelectCell, vbLf)`

Answer (score 0):

### Get Criteria Substrings

**The Function**

```
Function GetCriteriaSubStrings( _
    ByVal InitialString As String, _
    ByVal CriteriaString As String, _
    Optional ByVal sDelimiter As String = ",", _
    Optional ByVal dDelimiter As String, _
    Optional ByVal CompareMethod As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare) _
As String
    Dim Dat() As String: Dat = Split(InitialString, sDelimiter)
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(Dat)
        If InStr(1, Dat(i), CriteriaString, CompareMethod) > 0 Then
            Dat(r) = Dat(i)
            r = r + 1
        End If
    Next i
    If r > 0 Then
        If dDelimiter = "" Then
            dDelimiter = sDelimiter
        End If
        ReDim Preserve Dat(0 To r - 1)
        GetCriteriaSubStrings = Join(Dat, dDelimiter)
    End If
End Function
```

**VBA**

```
Sub WriteCriteriaSubStrings()
    Range("C4").Value = GetCriteriaSubStrings(Range("B4").Value, "Apple", vbLf)
End Sub
```

**Excel**

```
=GetCriteriaSubStrings(B4,"Apple",CHAR(10))
```